# Mapreduce mapper to pass both key and value as text fields

Tags: java, mapreduce, inputformatter

I have a small project where I have a file with 2 tab-separated text columns.
I want my mapper to read them from the file and set the second column as key and the first column as value to the reducer, but I can't seem to get it done.
Then, I want to pass the (key, value) pairs to reducer where it will create for each key a list of all its values.

```
public static class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text site = new Text();
    private Text tag = new Text();

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) 
                        throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString(), "\t");
        while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
            site.set(itr.nextToken());
            tag.set(itr.nextToken());
            context.write(tag, site);
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting an error on the `conext.write` line.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value (site) you're writing in `context.write(tag, site);` is a `Text` object but you have `Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>`. You should change this to `Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text>`.

At the moment you're telling it you're going to output an `IntWritable` as the value.

You can also remove `private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);` since it isn't being used.